# Hex in a stringWithFormat BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Here is a part of my code:

I have a string which is formed by a stringWithFormat like this:

```
NSString * DestChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Dest1String];
```

The Dest1String is formed like this:

```
NSString * Dest1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", [Dest1OutField integerValue]];
```

The Dest1OutField is a NSTextField

When I put "10" in my text field, the DestChoice string result in "A" so my code is working.
When I put "11" in my text field, the DestChoice string result in "B", this is good too.
But If put "31" i'm supposed to get "1F" but I have a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" crash...

I don't understand... If someone can light my way... :)

Thans in advance!

---

EDIT:

So, I'm always stuck...
I edited my code to be "more understandable" and I give you the exact code which I use, not an sample:

So, I make two strings like this:

```
DestChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", [DestField integerValue]];
SourceChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", [SourceField integerValue]];
```

So the user write the Source/Dest in Decimal value but they are stocked as hex in a string, and then I have a button which reformat the source & dest like this:

```
NSString * CommandReadyToSend  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X:0/%@,%@\r", DestChoice, SourceChoice];
```

My code is working, BUT, strangly some values makes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the CommandReadyToSend part...
Example: If I write 1 in my text field => I receive 1 (hex value) as result in DestChoice
If I write 10 in my text field => I receive A in DestChoice

BUT If I write 31 in the text field, I'm supposed to get 1F, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
Same thing with 29 (dec value)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * DestChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", Dest1String];
```

You are indicating that you want to format two objects with `%@%@`, but you are only supplying a single object (`Dest1String`).

Comment: I edited my code (sorry, i didn't copy/paste, I writed it just right now, the problem is not coming from that) :/

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I am seeing with your code is

```
NSString * DestChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringWithFormat:@"%@", Dest1String];
```

Instead, you could use

```
NSString * DestChoice = [NSString stringWithString:@"%@", Dest1String];
```

Other than that, there is no problem. I am getting correct result.

Comment: I made a mistakes, my code is what you suggest. But I have the EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I put a number like 31 which is supposed to result in "1F"... I don't understand why...

Comment: Instead you could use `DestChoice = Dest1String`, there's no point creating a string from a format if the formatted string is just the same as the input string.